# Until now, Blair had refused

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect, past-perfect

*Until now, Blair had refused to link the two, insisting instead in the lead-up to the war that sending western troops would deny jihadis an arena and prevent Saddam Hussein from using them as proxies in his standoff with the west.*

Source: https://www.theguardian.com/world/2015/oct/25/tony-blair-is-right-without-the-iraq-war-there-would-be-no-isis

I am a little bit puzzled by the usage of past perfect ("Blair had refused…"). Given the fact that the time is localized by "until now", I would await the present perfect ("Blair has refused…").

Comment: "Now" there refers (semantically) to the very recent past (the interview). The past perfect is fine with respect to repeated statements over the past 12 years. **Now** is  the part that requires the listener's indulgence.

Comment: @TRomano +1 for felicitous phrase _listener's indulgence_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Now* does not necessarily refer to the "present", the time when it is spoken or written; it refers to the time you are talking about. If the clause it occurs in refers to the past it means "at that time", the time when the events you are narrating occurred.

> With his days as a fighting man behind him Wellington now turned his mind to a new career in politics.